# Adding a new item to the store of a dojo tree does not trigger an update

Tags: dojo, tree

I'am trying to add a new node to a dijit.tree by adding the node to its store.
The node is added to the store but the treeModel is not updated.

Here the setup of my store, model and tree

```
this.treeStore = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({
    target:"dn/",
    idAttribute:"serviceId",
    labelAttribute:"name"
});


this.treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
    store: this.treeStore,
    rootLabel:'All Files',
    deferItemLoadingUntilExpand: true,
    mayHaveChildren:function(item){ return item.children != undefined && item.children.length>0},
    childrenAttrs: ["children"]
});

this.docTree = new dijit.Tree({
    id:"myTree",
    showRoot:false,
    model: this.treeModel,
    persist: false,
},this.dijitTree);
```

Here the function which adds the item

```js
function addNewNode(item){
    var self=this;
    console.log(item);

    this.treeModel.getRoot(function(root){
        var tmp=self.treeStore.newItem(item,{parent:root, attribute:[]});
        self.treeStore.save();
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
The above code woks it was just an update problem

Comment: Just for sanity checking, can you try doing a getChildren on Forest Model to see if the changes were passed to the store?

Comment: Hi missingno. Turn's out I only had an update problem... the scripts on the server where not up to date XP. Anyway, the above code works and I think some of us could use it as a base for their development. Should I change the Question to "How do I add a new Item to a dijit Tree"?

Comment: Do as you please. I'd just note that it is a little different if you use the new dojo.store api instead: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/store_driven_tree/

Comment: this is new huh? did not see the tutorial until now... thanks for the link

Comment: I'm a little confused now... in the tutorial they use JsonRest and not jsonreststore, what are the advantages/disantages of the two?

Comment: The stores they use there conform to the new dojo.store api. The dojo.data api will eventually be deprecated but you shouldn't worry about it too much since what you have is already working.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
store.newItem(item);
store.save();
theGrid.setStore(store);
theGrid.update();
theGrid._refresh();
```

Comment: store.save() is mandatory after calling newItem(). Thanks for the point +1